# Correct way to fix UIToolbar position after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uitoolbar

I set toolbar by this code for portrait orientation:

```
    self.toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
```

It has a gap in landscape orientation because status bar is hidden by default:

[image]

Do I need to update toolbar frame each time (in order to avoid the gap) when device is rotated and check orientation when current view is loaded?

**OR**

there is another way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add constraints on your toolbar instead of setting the frame:
Something like this

```
    self.toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topLayoutGuide][toolbar(toolbarHeight)]" options:0 metrics:@{@"toolbarHeight": [NSNumber numberWithInt:44]} views:@{@"toolbar": self.toolbar}, @"topLayoutGuide":self.topLayoutGuide}]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[toolbar]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"toolbar": self.toolbar}]];
```

Comment: in this case toolBar is overlapped with status bar in portrait orientation

Comment: @sx00 Check my edited answer. That should do it. I had not accounted for the topLayoutGuide.